# Etimología de mantequilla (manteca)

Tags: etimología, historia, comparación-de-idiomas

Sé que es un derivado de `manteca`, pero me llamó la atención lo siguiente:

1. En italiano, inglés, francés, alemán, islandés y holandés, la forma más común para referirse a la mantequilla derivó del latín *butyrum*. **¿Por qué en Español, `butiro` (también derivado de *butyrum*) cayó en desuso?**
2. `Mantequilla` es derivado de `manteca`, **¿cuál es el origen de esta palabra?** He visto varios diccionarios donde se marca el origen como incierto o debatido.

Comment: Probablemente será una palabra ibérica o celta o incluso vasca (pero de una forma antigua cuyos restos ya no tenemos).  Como tenemos poquísima información de estos idiomas, no podemos decir mucho más.  Lo único es que es una palabra que se usa en todos los idiomas ibéricos excepto el euskera moderno, y no en ningún otro idioma derivado del latín.

Comment: Además, hay quienes dicen que viene del latín «mantica» (*odre*) que se usaba para hacer la mantequilla, pero probablemente no ha sido posible trazar este uso desde el latín al romance.  (*manteca* ya se usó en el siglo XVIII en traducciones cultas del árabe, y a menos que hubiese textos en latín con dicho significado podríamos probablemente descartar un origen latino)

Comment: Siempre he considerado `mantequilla` como un diminutivo de `manteca` de la misma manera como `platino` es un diminutivo de `plata`, al menos de punto de vista etimológico.

Comment: Ups, queria decir siglo XIII no XVIII (gran diferencia!)

Comment: @enxaneta `mantequilla` y `manteca` son dos cosas distintas. De todas maneras en algunos países usan otras palabras, por ejemplo sé concretamente que en Argentina usan `manteca` para referirse a lo que en Chile es `mantequilla` (o puede que sea al revés).

Comment: @enxaneta `Manteca` comes from the pig's fat and `Manquilla` comes from cow milk and cow fat and some kind of process. 
`Mantequilla` you can eat it with bread as a morning breakfast. On the contrary, `Manteca` would be kind of gross to spread and eat with bread. `Manteca` you would use to fried stuff just like you would use oil.

Comment: @VladimirNul - es usted gracioso. Se que `mantequilla` y `manteca` son dos cosas distintas. De la misma manera como `platino` no es la misma cosa que `plata`, o como `horquilla` no es lo mismo que `horca`. Me refería **de punto de vista etimológico**

Comment: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?manteca: La palabra manteca parece ser una voz prerromana y estar relacionada con una raíz indoeuropea *menth- (revolver, mezclar) que dio, manthaja en sánscrito (manteca de nata) y сметана (smetana = crema agria) en ruso.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Why is Spain different?

There often isn't a clear 'why' in these kinds of questions - different languages evolve differently, and though some might be relatively geographically close, or have a common ancestor, the evolution and adoption of new words doesn't happen uniformly  across such languages.

There are many words in Spanish where it is not cognate to the translation in non-Iberian western European languages. E.g:

[image: Beer]

[image: Sister]

[image: Chess]

[image: Table]

[image: Banana]

[image: Pineapple]

[image: Window]

## 2. Etymology of *mantequilla*

*Mantequilla* comes from *manteca*, which is an old word in Spanish, appearing in the earliest documents we have, e.g:

> E el fue a las bacas e aduxo un bezerro tierno e lech e **manteca**, e adobolo e pusolo sos el arbor.
>
> - *La fazienda de Ultra Mar*, Almerich (c.1200)

> Et uobis Tellus Petri de los ganados que ibi traderetis, accipietis de las ieguas los potros, & de las baccas los boues, & caseum & **mantecca**m, & de las oues los carneros, & caseum & lanam, & de las porcas los porcos, hi nos que uos lo contengamos de pan; & de istos canados aueth poder de sachar en la meetate quando nunquam uolueritis, & post uostrum obitum remaneat la medietate del ganado que ibi fuerit ahora, toto remaneat alla meson;
>
> - *Carta de donación [Documentos del Reino de Castilla]*, 1181

There are cognates in other ibero-romance languages (`pt` `gl` *manteiga*, `ast` `cat` *mantega*, `arg` `esp` *manteca*) and it first appears at a similar time in [Old Portuguese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manteiga#Etymology) "... already attested with this spelling in a Galician Latin document from 1118"

Its exact origins are uncertain, but Corominas posits the following connections:

> [image]
>
> - [*Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico*](https://losapuntesdefilosofia.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/diccionario-etimolocc81gico-abreviado-de-la-lengua-castellana-joan-corominas.pdf), Joan Corominas